# How to download multi files from swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-codegen

I've an issue when try to download file from swagger.

When I compiled a code with config below, I got an error:

> Could not find goal 'download' in plugin io.swagger:swagger-codegen-maven-plugin:2.3.1 among available goals generate

I've tried to break to 2 plugins and it compiles successfully, but just one file is downloaded.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>download</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <api>Addresses</api>
                <owner>test</owner>
                <version>2.13.0</version>
                <format>yaml</format>
                <token>test</token>
                <outputFile>${address-service-swagger.file}</outputFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>aec</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>download</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <api>Shipper</api>
                <owner>test</owner>
                <version>2.13.0</version>
                <format>yaml</format>
                <token>test</token>
                <outputFile>${shipper-service-swagger.file}</outputFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

By the way, I want to define `outputFile` is a file in the folder target, and I've tried to change `outputFile` by the target path, but It compiles fail. Do you have any idea for this case?

Thank you for your helps

Comment: You seem to have confused [`swagger-codegen-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/modules/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin) with [`swaggerhub-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swaggerhub-maven-plugin/). The former has the `generate` goal to generate server/client code, the latter has the `download` goal to download API definitions from SwaggerHub. If you explain what exactly you are trying to achieve we could suggest the correct configuration.

Comment: Thanks @Helen, this is my mistake, I've changed **swagger-codegen-maven-plugin** by **swaggerhub-maven-plugin** and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, to download API definitions from SwaggerHub you need to use the [`swaggerhub-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swaggerhub-maven-plugin/), not [`swagger-codegen-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/modules/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin).

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swaggerhub-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    ...
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong plugins and you can do like this
If your swaggerhub api link is like this `https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/massivebet/betting/0.9.0` then you config this and run

`mvn clean generate-resources` to download as yaml file

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swaggerhub-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.8</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>download</goal>
        </goals>

        <configuration>
          <api>betting</api>
          <owner>massivebet</owner>
          <version>0.9.0</version>
          <host>api.swaggerhub.com</host>
          <format>yaml</format>
          <token>your token if private apis</token>-->
          <outputFile>target/test.yaml</outputFile>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```